# why is ionic/angular refusing to authenticate?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, ionic-framework

I've built an authentication app that receives user info and token (jwt) from the server. I store the data localy and then use it to do more computation in the app. for the route guard, if the the token is available it, should go to the dashboard else return back to login.

**this is my auth serve and I am calling the loggedIn method**

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http"
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private _registerUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/register"
  private _loginUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/login"
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _router:Router,private storage: Storage) { }
  registerUser(user){
    return this.http.post<any>(this._registerUrl,user)
  }

loginUser(user){
 return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl,user)
}

loggedIn(){
  return !!this.storage.get('token')
}

getToken(){
  return this.storage.get('token')
}

logoutUser(){
  this.storage.remove('token')
  this.storage.remove('user')
 this._router.navigate(['/login'])

}
}
```

**routing file**

```
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardPage } from './dashboard/dashboard.page';
import {HomePage } from './dashboardComponents/home/home.page'
import {MessagesPage } from './dashboardComponents/messages/messages.page'
import {PaymentsPage } from './dashboardComponents/payments/payments.page'
import {PostedJPage } from './dashboardComponents/posted-j/posted-j.page'
import {ProfileEditPage } from './dashboardComponents/profile-edit/profile-edit.page'
import {PostPage } from './dashboardComponents/post/post.page'
import {SettingsPage} from './dashboardComponents/settings/settings.page'
import { PasswordResetPage } from './password-reset/password-reset.page'
import { JobCompletedPage } from './dashboardComponents/job-completed/job-completed.page'
import { AppliedJobsPage} from './dashboardComponents/applied-jobs/applied-jobs.page'
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard'
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
  { path: 'password-reset', component:PasswordResetPage, pathMatch:'full' },
  { path:'dashboard', redirectTo:'dashboard/home/1000}'},
  { path:'dashboard', component: DashboardPage,canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    { path: 'messages', component:MessagesPage , pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: 'home/:distance', component: HomePage , pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: 'payments', component:PaymentsPage , pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: 'post', component:PostPage ,pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsPage, pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: 'profile-edit', component: ProfileEditPage, pathMatch:'full' },
  {path:'posted', component:PostedJPage,pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'job-completed', component:JobCompletedPage, pathMatch:'full' },
  {path:'applied-jobs',component:AppliedJobsPage,pathMatch:"full"}
  ]
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const components = [
  HomePage,
  MessagesPage,
  PaymentsPage,
  PostedJPage,
  ProfileEditPage,
  DashboardPage,
  PostPage,
  SettingsPage,
  PasswordResetPage,
  JobCompletedPage,
  AppliedJobsPage
];
```

***guard file***

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree,CanActivate,Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService} from './auth.service'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router:Router){

}

canActivate(): boolean {
   if(this._authService.loggedIn()){
     return true
   } else {
     this._router.navigate(['/login'])
      return false  
   }
 }

}
```

I am using ionic storage since I'll eventually launch it on the playstore. Whether the token is there or not, it still goes to the dashboard page even though I have a guard on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

modify your LoggedIn method to return promise (remove !!)

```
loggedIn() {
    return this.storage.get('token').then((token)=>{
      if (token) {
        console.log("token true")
        return true
      } else {
        console.log("token false")
        return false
      }
    })
  };
```

modify CanActivate like so:

```
async canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    if(await this.auth.loggedIn()){
      return true
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/login'])
      return false  
    };
  };
```

Comment: I am now getting "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'boo
lean'" . as the error

Comment: @georges sorry I did not notice !! initially. So doublebangs basically make your method return boolean even before Promise (of Storage) is resolved. So you keep getting false value. One fix could be to get rid of !!, allow your loggedIn method to return actual promise (of Storage) and thus be able to use "then". Another way could be to turn loggedIn to async function and make it return boolean after Promise has been resolved. Let me know if still have issues

Comment: its returning "error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value." on the canActivate method. I tried setting loggedin to a sync method and also tried remove !! and it returns the same error –

Comment: I see, seems like canActivate may return Promise as well. I will update answer with another solution

Comment: it still does not work after I impletemented what you wrote. Any further help would be great as I am confused.

Comment: OK - I will try to recreate your issue using stackblitz. I will share link here and will need your help to make it as close to your implementation as possible, WIll do in 1 hour or so

Comment: I think I got it working on my machine;) updating answer

Comment: Sergey Rudenko. I love you. Thank you. I am new to this and I am learning myself. You saved me. Thank you